# Looking for advice repairing granite stair tiles

Tags: tile, exterior, stairs, stone, granite

[image]

Hi! I have granite tiles on the front porch stairs with an overhang consisting of a smaller strip of tile bonded underneath the larger surface tile. The undersurface tile strip of the top step has separated (see picture below, compared to how it should look on the second step). Any advice on what adhesive I can use to stick it back together and any advice on the process?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Search brings up a few adhesives for granite.  Most of them should work if you do a good cleaning of the surfaces and possible clamping for the required drying time.

Answer (score 7):

Jack gave a great answer and I've upvoted it, but I'd rather see you use a polyurethane construction adhesive, which is made for a job like this, instead of a silicone caulk. I've seen silicone caulk lose its grip when exposed to the weather.

I've used Loctite PL Premium construction adhesive outdoors on masonry, and it's amazing. It can even be applied to damp masonry and still make a perfect bond. One advantage of this product over silicone is that it's easy to apply a very thin coat, which will help you get a very thin weld line between the two pieces of granite.

Follow Jack's prep instructions and check fit before applying the adhesive. I believe any excess can be wiped off with mineral spirits before it cures. Please check the label for that.

[image]

Photo credit: Home Depot

Answer (score 4):

That would be one of the places I would use silicone caulk, a full bed of it after the excess roughness from the old bond is cleaned up. This should or could be done with a right angle grinder with a masonry blade.

[image]

The long strip will crack real easy, so care must be used. The steps on either side are on their way out too. Once a crack starts.. it won't stop until it is separated. Silicone when given a full bed will keep out water and will give that little bit when needed. Hold the piece in place with 4 or more spring clamps.

[image]

Let the ooze dry, do not touch, clean with a single edge razor blade

Photos courtesy Harbor Freight(r)